# How to print upside down on even pages in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

I am working on an InDesign document with 6 pages but every second (even) page needs to be printed upside down, as it will be displayed as a flip chart style. How can I set up InDesign so that I won't have to design the even pages upside down, as it's not practical? is there a setting that can also help me save the document with such pages upside down for future distribution and printing in the right way? Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are printing to a duplex printer (a printer capable of two-sided printing), it's *often* a matter of setting the **printer options** correctly. You have to tell the printer to  align on the *long edge* to ensure you *don't* need to flip pages upside down. If the printer is set to align on the *short edge* then often it means the front/back of a single print is upside down with each other.

---

If you still need to flip pages and it's *not* merely a printer setting....

Design your pages upside down... But use the **Rotate Spread View** option to *view* the pages right side up in InDesign.

[image]

[image]

This allows you to *work* on a page and avoid the visual confusion, while ensuring the page will be *output* upside down.

The Rotate Spread View option only alters **what you see on screen** it doesn't change the direction the page will be output.

<sub>CS6 screenshots because that version is what I have launched. Should be very similar in CC</sub>